# How long were the Greek gods worshipped?

Tags: ancient-greece

When did the Greek gods reign end and how long did it last for them to be worshipped till when they were no longer worshipped?

Comment: The were worshiped from pre-history (between 1000 BCE and 3000 BCE) to about 400 CE. So between 1400 and 3400 years. A start date is difficult to identify because it occurred before writing. This system of mythology also evolved greatly during this time. If you don't need a formal source, start it 300 years before the [Iliad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad) at 1000 BCE, so 1400 years?

Comment: Search google for "Greek Gods Timeline"  -I found many charts that appear to answer your question. [this](http://www.personal.utulsa.edu/~marc-carlson/history/clam.html) is an example. As axsv177 points out, they begin in pre-history, and there are no known dates in pre-history.

Comment: They are worshipped even today. Google "Luddendorf" ...

Comment: [Related Question](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/18996/when-did-worshiping-of-ancient-greek-gods-come-to-an-end)